# How to get git to show changes A-B where A and B are branches

Tags: git

How to produce difference between two branches A, B as A-B (in the sense of sets). I don't want extra changes in B to be shown.

I have two feature branches say `A` and `B`. I had merged A to B in the past.
But I am not sure how much of A is in B. B has extra changes that are not in A.
Also in the recent past same changes where added to A and B as seperate commits rather than
cherry-pick from A to B. Note that A and B has seperate merge commits from `master` branch. I want to see how much of A is missing in B as changes.

I was able to get A-B in the format of commits, showing those commits which are in A but are missing in B.

```sh
git log --no-merges B..A
```

But above is of not much help when A and B has same changes with different commit. Want I want is A-B in the format of diff of changes in A that are not in B.

Answer (score 1):

You can step into one branch, then merge the other and then "uncommit" all the things that are different:

```
git checkout A --detach # in case you don't want to spoil branch A
git merge B
git reset --soft B
```

This is convenient because you can open files in IDE and it will highlight "changed" lines. And you'll be able to keep changing them if needed. Unlike the usual diffs that are static and can only be viewed in diff window.

Comment: What an interesting idea.

Comment: I'm trying this out... what do you mean by "open files in IDE"?

Comment: @matt I mean IDEs (at least JetBrains' ones) highlight changed lines. So if you have your project open in IDE - it will highlight files that are changed, as well as the changed lines in those files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure to understand which of the following you are looking for :

```
git diff B A
```

will give you the patch you would need to change B into the content of A ;

```
git diff B...A

# same as :
git diff $(git merge-base A B) A
```

will give you the differences between "the merge base of B and A", and A.

---

[edit] Ah, perhaps you are looking for `git log --cherry` :

```
$ git log --oneline --cherry B...A
= 52d74472c (HEAD -> A) update the thrusters
+ ca5649304 balance the hull   # commits tagged with "+" are not present on B
= 507c0acea fix the airlock    # commits tagged with "=" are also present on B
```

Note that this compares commits based on the patch they introduce ; if for some reason the patch is not exactly the same, two commits will be considered different.
This indicates the commits that `git rebase` or `git cherry-pick` would keep.

`git log --cherry-mark B...A` will display both lists for A and B, annotated with `+` and `=` to indicate "original" and "present on the other branch".