# Squash many pushed commits before merging into main

Tags: git, squash, git-squash

In a big refactoring branch, I was forced to do commits due to some git flaw (git loses track/history of moved files if too much of the content changes before committing), which left the repository with commits that are not "buildable".
To be on the safe side I also pushed these commits (nowadays, just in case should I get sick).
It would be great, if I could squash all that into one commit, either before or after merging main into my branch (and then back to main).
This is what it looks like:

```
main:    x --- x --- x --- x --- x
          \                     /
branch:    x' --- a --- b --- c
```

How it should look like in the end:

```
main:    x --- x --- x --- x --- x --- x
          \                       \   /
branch:    x'--- (manySquashed) --- m
```

Also because the intermediate steps of the refactoring are not of interest (the whole before/after is all that's of interest), I don't need many of the pushed commits as single ones.

In many posts I couldn't find the solution to this specific request (or I just don't understand git enough - I'm a newbie with git).

EDIT: git losing history explained:
What I basically have to do is extracting core functionality of a component into a base library for reuse by similar components. To not lose the history of many files (lot of edits in the past 8 years) that now go to the base library, I moved many files to the new folder. There's a naming convention applied to the files/classes that sort of marks where they belong to. As I move core functionality of lets say SpecialComponent1 to BaseComponentLib, the files/classes need an adjustment in their names. I found that after moving the files (not yet committed), when I then edit them (e.g apply the new name in the classes), git (using SmartGit) changes the "Modification" from "Renamed" to "Untracked" when the percentage of changes within the file crosses a certain amount. While I see the whole file history with "Modification" "Renamed", with "Untracked" there is none anymore. I found that I can only get around this problem when commiting the moved files before doing any edit (therefore I have the cluttered/many commits).

Comment: I'm currently at the 'c', just before doing any merging with the main branch.

Comment: You can "uncommit" all the changes in the branch and then create a single commit with everything: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62438026/886697

Comment: I fear that git will lose track/history of moved and heavily changed files again, if I do all in one. Do you think it will work anyway?

Comment: Have you looked at/tried `rebase`-ing your branch to squash the commits, leaving out whatever needs to be in a single commit? Then you can merge back and forth with main.

Comment: Can you edit your question, to add more context about your "track/history of moved and heavily changed files" ?

Comment: @LeGEC, hope it is well enough explained. I wonder whether this "keeping track when moved" is a SmartGit problem or a general git problem.

Comment: You can find docs or posts on how git detects renaming ; here is an explanation I wrote for another question : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60927364/86072), but I learned by reading far better explanations from other people :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To squash all commits `a--b--c` into one single commit, run :

```
git reset --soft x'
git commit
```